# Automate distribution fitting in R

Tags: r, distribution

I am trying to automate the process of fitting the most suitable distributions in R. 
I have an excel column containing Time to failure of an automobile product. I input the file in R and read the column. Now I want to use goodness of fit tests to determine which distribution fits the data best. I want the output as the results of all test for different distributions displayed in a table format to help compare between the results. 
Is it possible to automate the entire process with R and not do step by step for each distribution using functions like fitdistplus?
Any suggestions?
I used the log-likelihood function like this and it seems to be working fine. Which more tests can I use?
Here is the code for loglik function-

```
library(gdata)
Excel<-read.xls("Failtime.xls", sheet="CPART10", perl="perl.exe")
attach(Excel)
x<-Time_to_Fail
library(MASS)

distributions = c("normal","exponential","binomial""negative binomial","gamma","t","lognormal")
x = x[ x >= 0 ]
for ( dist in distributions ) {
print( paste( "fitting parameters for ", dist ) )
params = fitdistr( x, dist )
print( params )
print( summary( params ) )
print( params$loglik )
y<-params$loglik
}
```

Comment: There's a reason it costs money to buy `Eureqa` . The "best fit" is highly subjective, as well as depending on how you limit the type of functions you're willing to try. Your list, for example, leaves out Weibull and Bessel and double-peaked normal.

Comment: As Carl said, I'm not really sure if you want to be doing this.  It can be good to get to know the shape of these distributions, but I'm not sure how good it is here.  For example, I doubt you would have negative failure times, as using the Normal distribution would suggest.

Comment: Unlike both commentators above, a procedure for just practically testing _'What fits best?'_ to me seems pragmatic. Any misinterpretations may be the responsibility of the beholder. A question such as _'How should I measure and compare goodness of fit?'_, however, may be better handled at [stats](http://stats.stackexchange.com). I suspect this might become tricky when your model functions have different degrees of freedom, specifically when your dataset also contains censored event times.

Comment: Yeah agreed with you all. I came across this software called EASYFIT and was trying to acheive what that software does through R.

Answer (score 1):

The best software I've encountered for fitting distributions to failure data is Weibull++ from Reliasoft.  They describe their "Distribution Wizard" algorithm [here](http://www.weibull.com/hotwire/issue91/relbasics91.htm).  As good as this software is, it is only a tool and still requires expert judgement.  So I don't know if it's possible to truly automate distribution fitting.

[image]